# Не работает метод для указателя на объект класса

Tags: c++, классы, указатели

Есть класс HeadTeacher: Object -> Human -> Teacher -> HeadTeacher.
У него есть поле - массив указателей на объекты Teacher.

Моя проблема: Когда создаю объект HeadTeacher (325 строка) и ему в массив заношу указатель на объект Teacher(строка 343), то все работает.

Когда я делаю указатель на объект HeadTeacher (338 строка) и уже в его массив хочу занести указатель на объект Teacher (340 строка), то все зависает.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <strings.h>
#include <ctime>
 
using namespace std;
 
 
#define MAX_SUBJECTS 10
#define MAX_STR 256
 
#define VALID_SUBJ(subjectID) (subjectID >= 0 && subjectID <= MAX_SUBJECTS - 1)
#define VALID_GRADE(grade) (grade >= 0 && grade <= 5)
 
/*
 
    Иерархия: Object -> Human -> Student
                            \
                             -> Teacher -> HeadTeacher
 
*/
 
//Базовый класс
class Object
{
public:
    
    //обязательно деструктор должен быть виртуальным!
    virtual ~Object() { cout << "dtor Object" << endl; }
        
    virtual void printAbout() const = 0; //теперь класс Object считается виртуальным, его экземпляры создавать нельзя    
};
 
 
// Родительский класс
class Human: public Object
{
    char fio[MAX_STR];
    int yearBirth;
    int basicPay = 1000;
 
    
    
public:
    
    Human(const char* fio, int yearBirth): yearBirth(yearBirth)
    {
        strcpy(this->fio, fio);
    }
    
    ~Human() { cout << "dtor Human" << endl; }
    
    const char* getFIO() const { return fio; }
    
    int getBasicPay() const { return basicPay; }
 
    
    int getAge() const
    {
        time_t t = time(NULL);
        return (localtime(&t)->tm_year + 1900) - yearBirth;
    }
    
    virtual void printAbout() const override
    {
        cout << "Human::printAbout(...)" << endl;
        //Object::printAbout(); // можно вызвать реализацию по-умолчанию если она определена
        cout << getFIO() << " возраст: " << getAge() << " лет." << endl;
    }
};
 
// Класс - потомок 1
class Student: public Human
{
    int grades[MAX_SUBJECTS];
 
    
    void printGrades() const
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SUBJECTS; ++i)
        {
            cout << "Предмет №" << i + 1 << ": ";
            
            if( grades[i] )
                cout << " оценка " << grades[i];  
            else
                cout << "нет оценки";  
                
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    
public:
    
    Student(const char* fio, int yearBirth) : Human(fio, yearBirth)
    {
        memset(&grades, 0, MAX_SUBJECTS * sizeof(int));
    }
    
    
    void setGrade(int subjectId, int grade)
    {
        if(!VALID_SUBJ(subjectId) || !VALID_GRADE(grade)) return;
        
        grades[subjectId] = grade;
    }
    
    int getGrade(int subjectId) const
    {
        if(!VALID_SUBJ(subjectId)) return 0;
        
        return grades[subjectId];
    }
 
    
    float getFullPay() const 
    {
        float k;
        int countMarks[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SUBJECTS; ++i)
        {
            switch (grades[i])
            {
                case 1: {countMarks[0] += 1; break;}
                case 2: {countMarks[1] += 1; break;}
                case 3: {countMarks[2] += 1; break;}
                case 4: {countMarks[3] += 1; break;}
                case 5: {countMarks[4] += 1; break;}
            }
        }
        if (countMarks[1] > 0) {k = 0.0;}
        else if (countMarks[2] > 0) {k = 0.5;}
        else if (countMarks[3] > 0) {k = 1;}
        else if (countMarks[4] > 0) {k = 1.5;}
        return getBasicPay() * k;
     
     }
    
    virtual void printAbout() const override
    {
        cout << "Student::printAbout(...)" << endl;
        
        cout << getFullPay() << endl;
        
        Human::printAbout(); 
        printGrades();
    }
};
 
 
// Класс - потомок 2
class Teacher: public Human
{
    int subjects[MAX_SUBJECTS];
    
protected:
    void printSubjects() const
    {
        cout << "Ведет предметы:" << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SUBJECTS; ++i)
        {
            cout << "Предмет № " << i + 1 << ": ";
            if(subjects[i]) 
                cout << "Часов: " << subjects[i];
            else
                cout << "Не ведет."; 
            cout << endl;
        }
    }   
    
    
public:
    
    
    
    Teacher(const char* fio, unsigned short yearBirth) : Human(fio, yearBirth), subjects{}
    {
        //memset(&subjects, 0, MAX_SUBJECTS * sizeof(int));
    }
    
    virtual ~Teacher() { cout << "dtor Teacher" << endl; }
    
    void setSubject(int subjectId, int subjectHour)
    {
        if(!VALID_SUBJ(subjectId)) return;
        subjects[subjectId] = subjectHour;
    }
    
    int getSubject(int subjectId) const
    {
        if(!VALID_SUBJ(subjectId)) return 0;
        return subjects[subjectId];
    }
    
    float getFullPay() const 
    {
        int sumHour = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SUBJECTS; ++i)
        {
            if(subjects[i]) { sumHour += subjects[i];}
        }
        return getBasicPay() * sumHour / 60;
     
     }
    
    virtual void printAbout() const override
    {
        cout << "Teacher::printAbout(...)" << endl;
        cout << getFullPay() << endl;
        Human::printAbout(); 
        printSubjects();
    }
};
 
 
class HeadTeacher: public Teacher
{       
    Teacher** zams;
    int zamsCount;
    int zamsCapacity;
    
    void alloc(int capacity)
    {
        if(capacity <= zamsCapacity) return;
        
        //выделяем массив указателей!
        Teacher** zamsExtend = new Teacher*[capacity];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < zamsCount; ++i)
            zamsExtend[i] = zams[i];
            
        //не забываем удалить старый массив, т.к. он уже не нужен
        if(zamsCount) 
            delete[] zams;
            
        zams = zamsExtend;  
        
        zamsCapacity = capacity;
    }
 
    public:
    
    /*HeadTeacher(const char* fio, unsigned short yearBirth) : Teacher(fio, yearBirth)
    {
        memset(&subjects, 0, MAX_SUBJECTS * sizeof(int));
        zamsCount = 0;
        alloc(5);
    }*/
    
    HeadTeacher(const char* fio, unsigned short yearBirth) : Teacher(fio, yearBirth)
    {
        zamsCount = 0;
        alloc(5);
    }
    
    HeadTeacher(const HeadTeacher& other) = delete;
    HeadTeacher& operator=(const HeadTeacher& other) = delete;
    
    virtual ~HeadTeacher()
    {
        cout << "dtor HeadTeacher" << endl;
        if(zamsCapacity)
            delete[] zams;
    }
    
    void addZams(Teacher* newZam)
    {
        if(zamsCount == zamsCapacity) 
            alloc(zamsCapacity * 2); //всегда увеличиваем массив в 2 раза
        
        
        zams[zamsCount++] = newZam;
    }
    
    void printAboutZams()
    {
        cout << "Заместители " << zamsCount << " штук:" << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < zamsCount; ++i)
            cout << "Преподаватель: " << zams[i]->getFIO() << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }   
    
    float getFullPay() const 
    {
        return Teacher::getFullPay() * 1.6;
        
     }
    
    virtual void printAbout() const override
    {
        cout << "HeadTeacher::printAbout(...)" << endl;
        cout << getFullPay() << endl;
        Human::printAbout(); 
        Teacher::printSubjects();
    }
    
};
 
 
void printAboutObject(const Object* object)
{
    object->printAbout();
}
 
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    system("chcp 1251");
 
    //Object objAbstract; //[Error] cannot declare variable 'objAbstract' to be of abstract type 'Object'
    
    /*Student student("Петр", 2001);
    student.setGrade(3, 4);
    student.setGrade(5, 5);
    student.setGrade(9, 4);
    student.printAbout();
    cout << endl;
    
    Teacher teacher("Владимир Алексеевич", 1963);
    teacher.setSubject(3, 10);
    teacher.setSubject(6, 15);
    teacher.setSubject(8, 20);
    teacher.printAbout();
    cout << endl << "------------------------------" << endl << endl;
    
    */
    HeadTeacher hteacher("Петр Алексеевич", 1963);
    hteacher.setSubject(3, 10);
    hteacher.setSubject(6, 15);
    hteacher.setSubject(8, 20);
    hteacher.printAbout();
    cout << endl << "------------------------------" << endl << endl;
    
    
    Teacher* obj = new Teacher("Владимир Алексеевич", 1963);
    obj->setSubject(1, 10);
    printAboutObject(obj);
    cout << endl << "------------------------------" << endl << endl;
    
    HeadTeacher* obj2 = new HeadTeacher("Лешка Суслин", 1985);
    obj2->setSubject(2, 100);
    //obj2->addZams(obj);
    printAboutObject(obj2);
    cout << endl << "------------------------------" << endl << endl;
    hteacher.addZams(obj);
    //obj2->printAboutZams();
    hteacher.printAboutZams();
    
    delete obj; delete obj2;
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я вот просто не понимаю, почему один метод setSubject работает с указателем на объект класса.
А второй addZams - нет

Comment: @DmitryK, alloc в Teacher сделал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переменные в классах нужно инициализировать.
Вот смотрите по шагам:

- создается объект `HeadTeacher` конструктором с именем и годом рождения
- в нем вызывается `alloc()`
- в ней сравнивается `if(capacity <= zamsCapacity)`.
  А теперь вопрос - чему равен `zamsCapacity`? В результате, у вас иногда срабатывает эта проверка, а иногда не срабатывает. И когда она сработала, `return` выполнился и память в `zams` не выделилась. А потом вы в функции `addZams()` пишете туда значения и получаете UB.

```
class HeadTeacher: public Teacher
{       
    Teacher** zams;
    int zamsCount;
    int zamsCapacity;
    
    void alloc(int capacity)
    {
        if(capacity <= zamsCapacity) return; // zamsCapacity - случайное значение
        
        Teacher** zamsExtend = new Teacher*[capacity];
        ....            
        zams = zamsExtend;  
        zamsCapacity = capacity;
    }
 
    public:
    void addZams(Teacher* newZam)
    {
        if(zamsCount == zamsCapacity) 
            alloc(zamsCapacity * 2); //всегда увеличиваем массив в 2 раза

        zams[zamsCount++] = newZam; // память под zams не выделена!
    }
```

Comment: Уточню, что UB возникает ещё на этапе чтения `zamsCapacity` в условии.

Answer (score 0):

Я торопыга...
не инициализировал zamsCapacity...
Исправил и заработало, просто стыдоба...

```
HeadTeacher(const char* fio, unsigned short yearBirth) : Teacher(fio, yearBirth)
    {
        zamsCapacity = 0;
        zamsCount = 0;
        alloc(5);
    }
```

Comment: Лучше инициализировать их в *member initializer list* (где `Teacher(fio, yearBirth)`) или в *default member initializer* (где `int zamsCount;`), т.к. в текущем варианте это уже не инициализация, а присваивание.

Comment: @tocic ааа, понял